# Dimensions in Kmeans cluster plot

Tags: k-means, dimensions

I did a kmeans cluster plot to identify how my plants cluster based on  4 morphological traits of them. It gave me 3 clusters as shown in the figure. I'm not sure how to interpret these dimensions though. Do the 1st and the 2nd top dimensions explain 61% and 18% variation in my data set respectively? If so I want to know what are these two top dimensions? It's not mentioned anywhere in my out put.

Can someone  help?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87H3.jpg)

Comment: Could you share the example code?

Comment: Sure!! This is what I used.                                                                                                     #loading data
traits <- read.csv("kmean_final.csv",TRUE,",")

#scaling data
traits_scaled <- scale(traits[-1])
row.names(traits_scaled) <- NULL
head(traits_scaled)

k3 <- kmeans(traits_scaled, centers = 3, nstart = 25)
str(k3)


#visualization
library(factoextra)
fviz_cluster(k3, data = traits_scaled)

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263374/clusters-and-data-visualisation-in-r here is the answer on your question.